# How to set currentdate into OracleCallableStatement

Tags: java, oracle

Its very silly question but really not able to do that. 
How to set currentDate with OracleCallableStatement.

```
OracleCallableStatement callableStatement = null;
            con = this.dataSource.getConnection();
            callableStatement =
                (OracleCallableStatement) con.prepareCall("call demo.test.ESTIMATE_TP(?)");
                             java.sql.Date currentDate = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
            callableStatement.setDATE(5, currentDate);
```

Please find the screen shot as for better understanding. 
Thanks in advance. [image]

Comment: looks like it needs a `oracle.sql.Date` object

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I have changed the implementation. Switch to more generic solution CallableStatement instead of OracleCallableStatement.